# Which Native American character threw a speeding bison onto its back in an old X-Men comic?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, character-identification

I saw this a long time ago, and just remembered it recently. The character in question was a native American; he runs up to a speeding bison, grabs it by the horns (literally) and throws it to the ground on its back.

I know it was an X-Men comic because the same comic showed Colossus turning his skin to steel and moving to save his sister from being chewed up by a combine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thunderbird aka John Proudstar, brother to James Proudstar aka Warpath.

The comic you're remembering is *Giant-Size X-Men* #1 (1975). It's Thunderbird's first appearance.

[image: Thunderbird throws down a bison]

Indeed, ealier in the issue Peter saved his sister from being run down by a tractor.

[image: Peter saves his sister]

Comment: FYI - it's the first appearances of Storm, Nightcrawler, and Colossus as well. And the little girl is Illyana Rasputin (a.k.a. Magik), so it's her first appearance as well.

Comment: @RDFozz I was surprised to find out it was Thunderbird, to be honest. You say "native American mutant" and I hear "Warpath" before I think of Thunderbird, so today I learned they didn't debut in the order I thought :) and yeah, lots of people debuted in that one. Gotta live up to the Giant-Size, ahah!

Comment: Yeah, James (Warpath) is John's little brother. You don't see much of John, since he dies two issues later. He may be #2 on the list of characters who've stayed dead, after Uncle Ben.

Comment: I guess his minimal appearance in the comics is part of why they decided to use John Proudstar (Thunderbird) in the X-Men universe TV show *The Gifted*.

Comment: My goodness, that is an terrible portrayal of a Native American character. It checks all the boxes. He's a proud warrior longing for the glory days the Apache, check. He hunts buffalo, check. The implied sexism and the obligatory mention of "squaws" (an Eastern Algonquin language family word, not Apache) check. And because he's a mutant, he can have literal red skin! :(

Comment: At least Colossus only has to suffer from being named after the first famous Russian who came to the mind of the writer. And, perhaps, being an almost literal Stalin (a man of steel).

Comment: @Jenayah you just made me feel old

Comment: @RDFozz - Why is Illyana just called "the child"? Does Colossus not know that's his sister??

Comment: @Malandy that's just '70s writing :P

Comment: @Malandy she's indeed her sister, as written in [the panel before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPP11.png)

Comment: @Adamant - Particularly unfortunate with the Apache, who were matrilineal. Otherwise though, this may well be a fairly accurate portrayal of how a young 70's Apache raised in a eurocolonized culture felt about things. There was a [lot of anger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Indian_Movement) back then.

Comment: @T.E.D - Ehhhhhh, maybe. A literally red-skinned, Buffalo-hunting proud warrior race stereotype isn't precisely the same as, say, a yuppie grappling with their feelings about European colonization, to my mind. He's not exactly talking about "economic independence for the Indians" a la AIM (that would have been too much for their readers!); he seems more an excuse to have a standard Western-type Native character.

Comment: Well, now "the child" makes more sense as a descriptor.

Comment: @Adamant - Interesting. The one person I personally know who was part of AIM, I don't think you could really call him a "yuppie". Dude was best friends with my dad, but grew up with literally no money. I mean none. I kind of get the impression that was the typical backstory for an AIM activist.

Comment: @T.E.D.- Since we're talking about a Marvel comic book, you want to clarify this isn't Advanced Idea Mechanics....

Comment: @Adamant - As I recall, a later writer decides the shared name isn't a coincidence, and these Rasputins are related to *the* Rasputin.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I'm sure that's true, but my point was more about the difference between a nuanced depiction of a person clearly from the 70s who is angry about the issues facing Native Americans, and a character like this, who's "traditional" to the point of just embodying stereotypes. Particularly telling is that in a depiction like this, the focus is on him blaming *the Apache* for not being what they used to be, as opposed to the more realistic focus of him blaming the larger society for what's happened.

Comment: @Adamant he's got his fair share of "white men are the bad guys don't talk to me white cripple" in [the next page](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/Wpgq-A_cHiKtYl25ZFQEIpkugZpzyOnsspgC4S8KKiNnnvRZYhJT3Y2z0ZqOz7sWxGdZGIcOSZL7=s1600), and it's as stereotypical as you can imagine :/

Comment: @Adamant - OK, I get you.